# Can a manifold have infinite Minkowski dimension?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, dimension-theory-analysis

If $M$ is a topological $n$-manifold, then I know that there is a metric $\rho$ (compatible with the topology) such that the Hausdorff dimension of $(M,\rho)$ is $n$ (see [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/191785/the-relation-between-hausdorff-dimension-of-an-n-manifold-and-n)). Is this also true for the Minkowski (upper box counting) dimension? I wouldn't be surprised if not, as it seems to behave much more volatile than Hausdorff dimension. In that case, is there always a metric such that the Minkowski dimension is at least finite?

If this is not easy to answer, are there some additional assumptions on $M$ that change this (differentiable, smooth etc.)? I know that Falconer mentions that the Minkowski dimension is always $n$ if $M$ is a smooth submanifold of some $\mathbb{R}^m$, for example.

Comment: I think you are misstating the result quoted in the link. All what it says is that the infimum of Hausdorff dimensions equals $n$, there is no claim that the infimum is realized.

Comment: @Moishe Kohan Pablo Shmerkin says in his answer "_The topological dimension equals the infimum (**which is in fact a minimum**) of the Hausdorff dimensions of (X,ρ) where ρ varies among the metrics compatible with the topology of X_", does he not?

Comment: Oh, you are right, I did not notice this. Incidentally, I do not think the box counting dimension makes sense for spaces which are not subsets of $R^N$. However, what Szpilrajn (Marczewski) proves in http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/fm/fm28/fm28111.pdf is that every separable metrizable topological space of dimension $n$ is homeomorphic to a subset $E$ of $R^{2n+1}$ whose Hausdorff dimension is $n$. Possibly, if you look closely at the construction of $E$, you will also see that its Minkowski dimension is $n$ as well. But his proof shows that Minkowski dimension is $\le 2n+1$.

Comment: @MoisheKohan That's really helpful, thanks! Just to make sure I understand correctly: Given this homeomorphism $\phi\colon M\to E\subset \mathbb{R}^{2n+1}$ (where $M$ is the $n$-manifold), I define a metric on $M$ by pulling back the Euclidean metric on $E$ via $\phi$, which is compatible with the topology on $M$ because $\phi$ is a homeomorphism, and w.r.t. this metric, the Minkowski dimension of $M$ is the same as that of $E$, so at the very least $\le 2n+1$. Is this correct? I'd be happy to accept this as an answer, if you so wish!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a theorem due to Edward Szpilrajn (Marczewski),

E. Szpilrajn, La dimension et la mesure", Fund. Math. 28 (1937) 81–89.

that every separable metrizable topological space of covering dimension $n$ is homeomorphic to a subset $E$ of ${\mathbb R}^{2n+1}$ whose Hausdorff dimension is $n$. You can find an English-language proof of this result in the book

*Hurewicz, Witold; Wallman, Henry*, Dimension theory, Princeton: Princeton University Press. 165 p. (1948). [ZBL0036.12501](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0036.12501).

(I will add a precise reference later: I do not have access to the book right now.)

At the very least, it follows that the Minkowski dimension of $E$ is at most $2n+1$, in particular, finite. (There is a good chance that the proof shows more, namely that it is $=n$.) In particular, every $n$-dimensional manifold can be metrized by a metric of   Minkowski dimension $\le 2n+1$.